# Why I can't get complete data from using Google Map api?

Tags: python, http, ssl, https, request

I created a Python project to test google map api. I occured problem when I test the first API:Nearby Search Requests.

I tried this url official doc provided:
*https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere*
if I put this url on my browser,I'll get perfect data on browser. Then I did nothing but created a python module , here is the code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  

import socket
import ssl 


sock = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket()) 
sock.connect(('maps.googleapis.com', 443)) 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('maps.googleapis.com', 443))
sslSocket = socket.ssl(s)
uri = 'GET /maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=MyKey HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:maps.googleapis.com\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\naccept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n\r\n'
sslSocket.write(uri)

data = sock.read()
print 'going to connect...'
print data 
s.close()
```

Unfortunately，the result on the console I got is like this ：

```
going to connect...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2013 08:05:59 GMT
Expires: Wed, 02 Oct 2013 08:10:59 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300
Vary: Accept-Language
Server: mafe
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

560b
{
"debug_info" : [],
"html_attributions" : [
"Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.yellowpages.com.au/\"\u003eYellow           Pages\u003c/a\u003e"],
"next_page_token" : "ClRHAAAA4lOaMlZcUjyndIqhBsHzyyU0nD5PHarmjgmnguj3morn7Em-    ipqhSR33V__d0kjrL4PzAqY7y4TAK7Uj3XzWjhoUchLBcBs-    TNFxWIvGst8SEArmj_T7_eDZWyr8UDGy5OEaFPFaK2yHDg7Kv2U3Obsy7opkQfEw",
"results" : [
{
"geometry" : {
"location" : {
"lat" : -33.8599827,
"lng" : 151.2021282
},
"viewport" : {
"northeast" : {
"lat" : -33.8552584,
"lng" : 151.2031401
},
```

this result is incomplete and I tried many times, the results are same. So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know if it is related with https protocol of google map api

Comment: Why are you not using stuff like `urllib` or [Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for making HTTP requests? I've never seen anybody use sockets for talking to a HTTP service.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using sockets for HTTP. Specifically, `sock.read()` is not guaranteed to read all the bytes that the other side has sent; instead, you have to keep asking it, until it returns an empty byte string. Then you can be sure you've received everything. But, sockets are really tricky, and it's almost never a good idea to use them, and it's almost always a good idea to prefer a higher level framework. For example, even `ssl_sock.write()` might actually not even write everything (or at least `sock.send()` definitely behaves this way) and instead returns the number of bytes sent, and if that's less than the data you passed to it, you have to retry with the rest of the (unsent) data.

Now, with HTTP, I've never before seen anybody use sockets. Instead use stuff like `urllib2.urlopen(...)` in [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or even better **[Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)**. Additionally, there are [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) and [httplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html). For example, with **Python Requests**, your code becomes as simple as:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=MyKey')
data = response.json()  # shortcut to `import json; json.loads(response.text)`
```

The simplest way to install Python Requests is with `pip install requests` (or `easy_install requests`). Or, if you'd rather prefer to avoid dependencies:

```
import json
import urllib

data_raw = urllib.urlopen('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&sensor=false&key=MyKey').read()
data = json.loads(data_raw)
```

And now, `data` is guaranteed to contain the entire reponse; you will never get partial responses.

**P.S.** If you need to pass along some HTTP request headers with your request, you can do that too:

```
requests.get(url, headers={...})
```

**P.P.S.** if you want to learn more about raw sockets (hopefully only for non-HTTP purposes), see **The Python [Socket Programming HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html.)**

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I tried your way and got complete data. The reason for I only using socket is that I can't guarantee the server I used can work with other lib well.

Comment: @VincentWang: There's no need for such guarantees: if it's a HTTP/HTTPS server, it **will** work with HTTP client libraries, especially since it's a Google server—there's no reason to suspect Google is not conforming to HTTP standards.

Answer (score 0):

`help(sock.read)` gives:

> Help on method read in module ssl:
>
> read(self, len=1024) method of ssl.SSLSocket instance
>       Read up to LEN bytes and return them.
>       Return zero-length string on EOF.

and your response is close to 1024 chars so try:

```
data = '  '
while len(data) > 0:
    data = sock.read()
    print data,
print "\nDone."
```

Comment: while technically correct, I don't think it's such a good idea to help a beginner make HTTPS requests with raw sockets :) He'll soon come back and ask help with parsing headers and stuff like that; so unless learning the internals of HTTP, it's probably not good for him.

Comment: True enough __but__ since the OP was already making raw requests... (this is why I already +1ed your answer that came up when I posted mine).

Answer (score 0):

the data is sent in multiple send and recieves. 
So you should run a loop to check till when the data comes with

```
receivedString = ""
While True:
    data = socket.recv(1024) #max length 1024
    #time.sleep(0.25)
    if(len(data) < 1):
       break
    recievedString = recievedString + data
```

Answer (score -1):

The first anwser is cool. But sometime you have to use original socket to solve problem...

So I tried it with my API Key using the code below

```
data = '  '
while len(data) > 0:
    data = sock.read()
    print data,
    print len(data)
print "\nDone."
```

while sometime the length of data is 1024 and sometimes is 381, I do not know why. In addition, the program will not jump out of the loop, which confused me too.

P.S. could anyone explain that what the "560b" in the beginning of the response content mean, thanks a lot.

Comment: -1 copy-paste from an existing answer + question + admitting you don't understand what's really going on.